# How does ArcMap decide ArcGIS Online and Basemaps are not reachable?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-online

I am currently at a remote location and even though I have internet access (i.e. I can browse the web but not very quickly), when I start ArcMap 10.1 the Add Data options for Add Basemap and Add Data from ArcGIS Online are greyed out.

Does anyone know why this might be, and whether there is a way I can force ArcMap to "try harder" to reach ArcGIS Online?

Comment: Does this thread help: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/61829-ERROR-ArcGIS-is-currently-not-connected-to-online-resources?

Comment: Thanks for the link but each thing I tried from there left them greyed out.  As soon as I switched to internet at my hotel (a slightly better connection) they started working fine.  I suspect it is some characteristic of their network connection getting in the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is now resolved by IT staff.  Solution came from someone for who English is his second language so I do not know exact details but it seemed to be related to there being two gateways present instead of the expected one.