# Unable to connect ArcGIS Online through ArcMap/ ArcCatalog ver.10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, arcgis-10.2

I have ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.I am trying to connect to ArcGIS Online from Arc-catalog (My hosted Services) but throws me an error saying to check Network connection.

> Error : " Error Has Occurred . Check your Network connection"

But I am able to connect to Arcgis online through web browser. I have ArcGIS Global account & ArcGIS online account as well.

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum !! 1.Check your firewall settings 2.Try to connect ArcGIS Online through ArcMap. 3 I assume that you have single machine (contains ArcGIS Desktop) and trying to connect ArcGIS Online through that machine

Comment: Also Check your proxy settings sometimes web browser detects automatically the proxy settings

Comment: This reminds me of a [**10.1 problem**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41822/how-does-arcmap-10-1-decide-arcgis-online-and-basemaps-are-not-reachable) I had in the Maldives last year - it may or may not be relevant